# Flex dropdown menu with submenu not opening in the proper position

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am building a dropdown menu that may contain submenus using CSS flex. Here is my code:

```
<div class="nav-menu-dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-open-left">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
          <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>Admin Menu</span></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
          <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Admin</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a>
            <div
            class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-submenu">
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Option 1</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-building"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Option 2</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <div class="dropdown-menu-divider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>User Menu</span></a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a>
        <div
        class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-submenu">
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User Option 2</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-users"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User Option 3</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Companies</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>End Of Options</span></a></li>
  </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-menu-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px red;
  top: 105%;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-open-left {
  left: initial;
  right: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu-item {
  display: relative;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; // top right botton left
}

.dropdown-menu-item:hover .dropdown-menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-menu-item:active {
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text {
  flex: 8;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-menu-title {
  color: $ux-theme-color-text;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.dropdown-menu-divider {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 1px -1px;
}
```

Strangely I cannot get my submenu to open right at the side of the hovered item. The submenus are appearing at the bottom of the container, both submenus in the same position.

I think this should be simple but I can´t find out what´s going on here. How can I show my menus just at the side of the hovered menu item?

The fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xu38Lr5f/)

Comment: I thought you wanted the submenus displayed on the side of the hovered items, not beneath them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight glitch in *positioning* - you can just add `position: relative` on `.dropdown-menu-item` - see demo below:

```css
.nav-menu-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px red;
  top: 105%;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-open-left {
  left: initial;
  right: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
}

.dropdown-menu-item:hover .dropdown-menu-submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdown-menu-item:active {
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text {
  flex: 8;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-menu-title {
  color: $ux-theme-color-text;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.dropdown-menu-divider {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 1px -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu-dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-open-left">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
          <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>Admin Menu</span></a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
          <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Admin</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a>
            <div
            class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-submenu">
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Option 1</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-building"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Option 2</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <div class="dropdown-menu-divider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>User Menu</span></a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
      <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a>
        <div
        class="dropdown-menu-container dropdown-menu-submenu">
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User Option 2</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-users"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">User Option 3</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <li><a href="#"><span><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon"><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-text">Companies</div><div class="dropdown-menu-item-with-icon-icon"><span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span></div></div></span></a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-item">
    <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><a href="#"><span>End Of Options</span></a></li>
  </div>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown-menu * {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;       /* NEW; establishes the nearest positioned ancestor 
                              (i.e., the bounding box) for abspos descendents */
}

.dropdown-menu-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 105%;            /* NEW */
  top: 0;                 /* NEW */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xu38Lr5f/1/